# Cannot read property 'run' of null error when connecting to a database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, bots, discord.js

I'm doing a bot with a coin system and when you try to connect it to database you get this error:

```
(node:17008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null
    at Promise (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\node_modules\sqlite\main.js:219:19)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Database.run (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\node_modules\sqlite\main.js:218:12)
    at sql.get.then.catch (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\index.js:67:7)
    at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
(node:17008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:17008) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**CODE:**

```js
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM coins WHERE userId = [message.author.id]`).then(row => {
  if (!row) { // Can't find the row.
    sql.run("INSERT INTO coins (userId, coins) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 0]);
  } else {  // Can find the row.
    let curAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) +0.3 (row.coins + curAmt);
    if (curAmt > row.coins) {
      row.coins = curAmt;
      sql.run(`UPDATE coins SET coins = ${row.coins + curAmt}, WHERE userId = [message.author.id]`);
    }
    sql.run(`UPDATE coins SET coins = ${row.coins + curAmt} WHERE userId = [message.author.id]`);
  }
}).catch(() => {
  console.error; // Log those errors.
  sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coins (userId TEXT, coins INTEGER)").then(() => {
    sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, coins) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 0]);
  });
});
```

But the bot runs, I don't understand what is the error, everything seems right to me.

Comment: Can you post your sqlite initialization code?

Comment: const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./coin.sqlite");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the database first

```
const sql = require("sqlite")
const db = sql.open('./coin.sqlite', { Promise });
```

Then you can use db.run/get

Source: [Sqlite Discord.js: Cannot read property 'run' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959219/sqlite-discord-js-cannot-read-property-run-of-null)

Comment: TypeError: db.get is not a function